# RxSwift bind on textField sending next after pushing another view

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I'm facing a weird problem when trying to navigate from `ViewA` to `ViewB` using RxSwift.

I have the follow code (it's just an example):

```
    emailTextField.rx.text
        .map { $0 ?? "" }
        .bind(to: viewModel.email)
        .disposed(by: bag)


    viewModel.email
        .asObservable()
        .filter { $0.isValidEmail }
        .subscribe(onNext: { value in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: viewBSegue, sender: value)
        })
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

The problem is, after `ViewB` get presented, the `subscribe` in my `viewModel` is called again, which lead to pushing `ViewB` again.

`email` variable in `viewModel` is a `PublishSubject<String>` and I'm using `RxSwift`|`RxCocoa 4.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this looks like a bug in RxCocoa, but maybe I'm not seeing something. The `text` observable (which is a `controlPropertyWithDefaultEvents` function) emits on *every* editing event, including `editingDidEnd`. I would have expected it to emit only on `editingChanged` or `valueChanged` events.

That said, you can just use the `.distinctUntilChanged()` operator to remove the duplicate emit.

It seems kind of odd that you would present a different VC immediately after the user entered a valid email. Note for example that "foo@bar.co" is a valid email but if my email is "foo@bar.com" I won't be able to enter the whole thing before the new VC presents.

Some other comments:

Where you have `.map { $0 ?? "" }`, there is an `.orEmpty` operator that does the same thing.

You are capturing a strong self in your subscribe which means your VC will never be able to be deleted from RAM. Unless your VC is the first one.

The `sender` in your perform segue should not be the user's email. It should be the object that is sending the message, in other words `self` in this case.

Comment: Thanks! Got it. For me it doesn’t make sense to emit events on ‘editingDidEnd’. Regarding your observations, this is just a sample code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.distinctUntilChanged()` so any events without changes will be filtered.